# How can I use a boolean value coming from container environment variable in Visual Studio Code settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm currently using container environment variables (exported by my `docker-entrypoint.sh`) to configure Visual Studio Code settings and it works perfectly with `string` values:

```json
{
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "${containerEnv:PHP_VERSION}",
}
```

However, when the values must be of type `number` or `boolean`, an issue arises (`DB_ASK_PASSWORD` contains either `true` or `false`). In fact, I'm forced to wrap the value into double quotes, producing an invalid `number` or `boolean`:

```json
{
    "sqltools.connections": [
        {
          "port": "${containerEnv:DB_HOST}",
          "askForPassword": "${containerEnv:DB_ASK_PASSWORD}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even if, in this specific case, `port` could work (for internal type conversion), `askForPassword` cannot. Being wrapped by double quotes, the `"false"` text is interpreted as as truthy value.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm asking? Removing the quotes does not help either:

```json
{
    "sqltools.connections": [
        {
          "askForPassword": ${containerEnv:DB_ASK_PASSWORD}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: where is this `${containerEnv}` variable documented?

Comment: the last example is **INVALID** json

Comment: @rioV8 https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/environment-variables#_option-1-add-individual-variables. I think they're aware that it's invalid JSON. To me, that seemed like a logical thing to try. Not sure if bolded caps was necessary in your comment :/

Comment: Of course I knew it's invalid...that Is the question.

Answer (score -5):

Settings do not support variables automatically. The extension using the setting has to implement variables.

Most likely `intelephense` does support the `${containerEnv}` variable and `sqltools` does not.

Comment: Not true. Vscode replaces variables before initialization.